How does the CPU load the BIOS?
Context about me - I never studied electrical engineering/computer science, so this is coming from the shaky foundations of self education.
I just wondered how the CPU first loads the BIOS.
Should I think of the CPU as a hardware black box that repeats the Fetch-Decode-Execute cycle ad infinitum, and contains some hardware logic to load the BIOS from flash if a condition only met at boot is detected?
Any help is much appreciated.

Doing << Fetch-Decode-Execute cycle >> can be hardware "oriented" ("start address PC counter" can change) as it can do "cold" boot or "warm" boot or any other wanted (external or internal start under some hardware conditions) ...

This question is better suited for Super User. They have almost 5000 questions tagged bios.

You might want to read some introductory book on any processor. It will enlighten you a lot.

The BIOS is just code in memory. It doesn't need to be specially 'loaded' before the CPU can Fetch-Decode-Execute it. The fact that this BIOS code is typically 'physically' located in a ROM, EEPROM, or similar physical memory instead of RAM doesn't make any difference to the CPU.

see also: the fantastic "building a 6502 computer" by ben eater, in which he explains how the now retro 6502 processor initializes. link to first video in the series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnzuMJLZRdU

A BIOS is a collection of software routines which makes software controlled input-output devices - such as disk drives and display/data transmission ports - work (at least in their most basic modes). This allows the boot process of the computer to progress, as the more advanced software can be loaded from disks or the network. The BIOS also tries to detect if some hardware doesn't respond as expected i.e. if it's faulty.
Computers have a piece of hardware which detects if the power has just been turned ON and activates the RESET signal (See NOTE). CPU and other hardware are designed so that an active RESET signal forces the them to start the program execution from a certain address of a certain piece of ROM (=read only memory). That program is an intermediate loader program (=bootstrap loader) which fetches the BIOS (often stored in flash memory) and the kernel part of the operating system from disks or network. The BIOS checks the condition of the hardware and then the kernel loads the full operating system.
The ROM which contains the bootstrap loader may well contain also the BIOS or a simplified version of it. In that case the routines for input/output and hardware settings and testing can be run without loading anything from disks or external devices.
NOTE
Reset signal can often be activated also in other ways. Some of them:

manually by pressing the reset button
by executing a certain software command
watchdog alarm circuit notices that the software doesn't execute certain checkmark instructions in the right order and timing. That's a plausible indication of a computer crash. The watchdog activates the reset signal to lift the system back to the tracks.


Thanks for taking the time to answer, this really helped me and my understanding.

fetches the finally used BIOS [...] from disks or network to the memory - On most systems (at least all x86 PCs and Macs), the BIOS is in ROM so the system can boot and display stuff on screen without needing either disks or network.  Only the OS kernel / bootloader / freestanding program is fetched from disk or network, long after the BIOS has run lots of code to detect hardware as you describe, configure the memory controllers, etc.  Some of the BIOS / firmware might be decompressed from ROM into RAM, but it could just run from ROM if stored uncompressed.  (@Momus)

At least for machines that commonly have a "BIOS" (PCs), there is no ROM, at least not a visible one, and no bootstrap loader. The BIOS is stored in a EEPROM chip or similar, and (from the perspective of the BIOS writer) immediately executes instructions fetched from there, i.e. the BIOS does not need loading at all. This answer is at best confusing and at worst grossly wrong. The BIOS is then responsible to fully initialize the CPU, RAM, other chips (chipset) and any busses (e.g. PCIe) and extension cards.

@RememberMonica: an EEPROM or Flash is effectively a ROM during normal operation (when you're not updating the BIOS), filling the same role that ROM / PROM / EPROM / EEPROM chips did in earlier PCs.  NAND Flash needs a controller for byte-addressable access, I believe, but the chipset takes care of that.  (Other answers point out that a secondary processor might do some init before de-asserting the reset pin on the main CPU to let it start booting with an environment where it sees Flash at the physical address it expects, if that address layout isn't already the power-on default state)

@PeterCordes if there was a point in giving wrong information, for example, because it simplified the explanation considerably, I would agree. But needlessly giving a wrong explanation for no gain is just a wrong answer (and the answer is wrong on a lot of levels). And what's worse, most modern PCs use a flash filesystem inside the BIOS flash chip that is upated regularly (e.g. at every boot), even before UEFI became ubiquitous. The days where config information was stored in the cmos clock are long over.

@RememberMonica: Ah, thanks for the correction that typical PCs do write their flash every boot instead of using battery-backed RAM.  Makes sense.

@RememberMonica, if you could go over everything that is wrong with this answer, and I follow it, I will unmark it as accepted.

Intel / x86 PCs
It's a trick question! ... Depending on your level of pedantry, "the CPU" of a modern PC doesn't "load" the first bits of the BIOS into memory - it's memory-mapped, and a supporting peripheral actually retrieves the first portion(s) of data from external storage... It's an immensely complex process to go from power button to BIOS on screen.
I'm not totally up-to-speed on the process for x86 PCs, but from what I understand, a single core of the processor runs while all others are halted. At the beginning, the storage containing the BIOS image (often SPI flash) will be mapped into the processor's address space, and the cache will be used as SRAM (as DRAM isn't available yet). The processor begins execution at the "Reset Vector", and the memory-mapped SPI flash means that the processor is able to do a simple read, while a peripheral inserts the required SPI operations to retrieve the requested data. From there, the BIOS will take care of performing the "Power On Self Test" (POST), performing DRAM initialization, and many other steps before continuing the boot process by handing off to a bootloader (e.g: GRUB), which finally loads and starts the operating system.
Oxide Computer have discussed the "no BIOS" approach to their systems, and it's eyeopening to read / hear about what they've managed to cut out, and what they need to do.
The BIOS is a massively over-complicated / glorified bootloader, which at the fundamental level provides routines to access disks and other storage in support of the early boot process (historically via Interrupt Calls, though this may be outdated with EFI). It also needs to maintain a significant level of backward- and cross-compatibility so things "just work".
These bigger systems will also have a separate supervisory system - for Intel this is called the Management Engine (ME)... it's a whole separate, invisible system that runs whenever the system has power, and has been the focus of some interesting security research.
Note: A previous version of my answer stated that the Management Engine took care of much of the early boot initialization in Intel processors - apologies for this error. While educating myself, I came across some interesting information: How Does an Intel Processor Boot? and Open Source Cache as RAM with Intel Bootguard.
Bigger ARM Embedded Systems
The larger ARM systems (think Applications Processors) have a wide variety of approaches for the early boot process, but they'll generally have a small "ROM Boot Loader" (RBL) burnt into the silicon, which is just about able to load a small amount of code (e.g: SPL for the i.MX family) from external storage - SPI, eMMC, etc... that then loads a larger bootloader from more complex storage (e.g: U-Boot, somewhat equivelant to the x86 BIOS), possibly involving partitions, filesystems and other structures.
Finally, once in U-Boot, it's "trivial" to load the system kernel and possibly a initial RAM disk from the filesystem, and off it goes.
The Raspberry Pi has a fairly unique process, where the GPU is actually responsible for coordinating the early boot processes - not "the CPU".
Smaller ARM Embedded Systems
Smaller ARM sytems (think Microcontrollers like STM32) have a similar but simplified boot sequence - they'll either start executing directly from built-in flash, or may start a ROM bootloader that is generally enabled by strapping a pin during reset... this will provide a handful of interfaces for basic firmware load operations (e.g: UART, USB DFU, etc...), but not much else.
In the early stages, only one core will be active (if the part even has more than one), and all the others will be halted - the "application" needs to take care of initialzing the other cores.
Note also, that none of the above touches on security features like Secure Boot, which involves keys and cryptographic signatures to ensure the code is what it's supposed to be.
Even Smaller Systems
Tiny things like AVRs will power on and just start executing code starting from a given address - much like the simple fetch-decode-execute process you identify in your question. If someone wants any form of bootloader, then that needs to be included in their firmware image.
AVRs specify that they start execution from the "Reset Vector", and that the instruction placed there "must"(?) be an "Absolute Jump Instruction" pointing to valid code... the simplicity is almost refreshing.
This process is much more similar to the older computer systems which will simply wake up and try retrieving an instruction from a set address.

POWER uses a separate (SPI based) configuration bus that allows an auxiliary processor to configure everything connected to the bus before the CPU even starts, so the entire physical memory map including DRAM and inter-processor interfaces are running before the first instruction is executed. In our last POWER board, the auxiliary processor had a small ELF loader to load OpenFirmware into RAM on the first socket, and all sockets then start from there. I suspect Intel ME is not that different these days.

“the simplicity is almost refreshing” I find it rather strange and annoying that bigger systems don’t have the same simplicity. What’s wrong with starting to fetch instructions from a certain address?

I think this description is slightly misleading when it comes to microcontrollers such as the STM32 series (which I think would fall under the "smaller ARM embedded systems" heading). Although they do have something called a "bootloader" in ROM, the usual startup sequence doesn't use that "bootloader" at all; the core simply starts executing instructions directly out of flash memory. The provided "bootloader" is used only for loading an application program into flash memory from an external source like a PC or a USB drive.

IIRC AVRs will happily run whatever there is at the start of memory on bootup. Usually, you'd put a jump there, since the following addresses are where the CPU jumps on interrupts (so they'd contain jumps to the interrupt handlers). But if you don't enable any interrupts, you can ignore all that and go with program code right there at the start.

@ilkkachu - interesting... I wondered if a valid jump was some form of "is it programmed" protection. I did read that you can repurpose the interrupt vectors if you're not planning to use them!

@SophieSwett quite right, thanks - I'll clarify!

@michael The "load instruction at a fixed address and start executing" because intractable for modern processors when they got complex cached memory and bus controllers that needed to be configured in a platform specific manner before it's possible to load anything.  In the old days, you just hard wired a (P)ROM to the appropriate address and were good to go.  A modern ARM can only fetch from cache.  So it starts with the cache as "tightly coupled memory" initialized from on chip ROM which has to program a memory and IO device before it can do anything.

No, ME is not involved in Intel CPU boot, other than exchanging some integrity information. DRAM is brought up by MRC in the UEFI. The Oxide stuff is a bunch of marketing, Intel has slim/embedded bootloaders: their automotive boot loader passes control to the OS in 500 ms and the system can bring up video in no more than 2 s, to meet a safety requirement for back up cameras.

@user71659 - thanks for correcting me... I'll do some more reading into it and rework my answer when I have a chance. info

@user71659 - I've done some reading, and reworded my answer around x86 boot... I'd appreciate your comments.

@Attie when you say "the storage containing the BIOS image will be mapped into the processor's address space" - could you explain how this is done - or at the very least, what does this?

Gee, what is this edit comment timer...
@Attie With the bigger ARM systems, is the RBL a circuit that is burnt into the silicon specifically designed to load that small piece of initial code? Do these bigger ARM systems then not have a BIOS?
Could you include what AVR stands for?
In your smaller ARM section, you say that the ROM bootloader is enabled by "strapping a pin during reset", can you explain what this means?

Usually the ‘CPU’ doesn’t.
A majority of systems fall into one of two categories:

The boot firmware is directly mapped into memory or is otherwise directly executable. The processor thus doesn’t ‘load’ anything, it just starts running code from the reset vector.
The bootstrap process is orchestrated by a secondary processor that is responsible for loading everything, initializing hardware as needed, and then starting the CPU in the right state. In this case, the CPU is never the one loading the boot firmware, it’s the secondary processor.

The original IBM 5150 PC, most early cartridge-based game consoles, most systems designed to run CP/M, and a majority of modern Harvard architecture microcontrollers all fall into that first category.
The second category is more interesting, and is where almost all modern systems that a layperson would typically refer to as ‘computers’ can be found.
On modern x86 systems, that secondary processor is known as the Management Engine (on Intel systems) or Platform Security Processor (on AMD systems), and it handles the bootstrap process by executing a tiny boot ROM in the processor itself that loads the ME/PSP firmware off of an SPI EEPROM or SPI Flash chip. The ME/PSP firmware then does basic stuff like DRAM training and system bus configuration, sets up the MMU so that the main processor’s boot code is located in the right place in memory, and then brings the main processor out of a reset state.
Typical modern POWER systems, as well as many modern ARM server systems, handle things very similarly to x86 systems.
The early models of the Raspberry Pi SBC based on the BCM2735/BCM2736/BCM2737  are a particularly interesting example of the second category because the secondary processor responsible for system bootstrap is actually the GPU. It includes an impressively complex embedded boot ROM that knows how to load the contents of a specific file from a FAT 32 filesystem on an MBR-partitioned block storage device as firmware for the GPU, and that firmware in turn contains a rudimentary bootloader that handles bootstrapping the CPU.


Should I think of the CPU as a hardware black box that repeats the Fetch-Decode-Execute cycle ad infinitum, and contains some hardware logic to load the BIOS from flash if a condition only met at boot is detected?

Yes.
This is significantly easier to explain in the old PC-AT model, so I'll talk about that rather than UEFI. Basically all CPUs start off with their instruction pointer at a known value ("reset vector"). This is usually not zero. For 8086 class CPUs it's near the top of memory. It is the responsibility of the memory controller to map that to the EEPROM. The CPU fetches its first instruction from there. Often that is a jump to wherever the "real" entry point of the BIOS is.
The basic model of the reset vector also works for microcontrollers, and specialist CPUs such as DSPs and GPUs. The Raspberry Pi for example boots the proprietary GPU first, which loads the firmware for the ARM CPU.
There are some practical complexities which have to be handled in the BIOS. For example, EEPROM is slow to read from, but DRAM does not function at power on and needs a certain amount of configuration and "training" to detect the timing. None of the PCIe peripherals work at startup either, so the BIOS has to detect enough of them to find a disk (or Ethernet) to start loading a bootloader from.

For more details on how x86 PC firmware initializes the DRAM controllers using code running on the CPU, see How Does BIOS initialize DRAM? - some of the first instructions run from ROM on the boot CPU core set control registers to enable "no-fill mode", aka "cache-as-RAM" mode.  So it can use at least a megabyte of L3 cache size as RAM without worrying about it being evicted randomly, while doing MMIO accesses to the IO registers for the memory controller.

In case of modern “desktop”-class applications CPUs, it is a complex process. Most such CPUs have a smaller supervisory CPU inside. That supervisor has to boot first and configure the user cores for use. That’s the case in both PC and mainline mobile CPUs.
So, the user cores don’t do anything much at first. The supervisor CPU loads its code and starts execution first. Eventually, the user cores are configured far enough that they can begin execution. They will run some sort of a BIOS, although they may need to run further initialization code that was loaded into their caches by the supervisor.
This complex process is compounded by the "secrecy" around the supervisor - in Intel lingo it’s called the Management Engine (ME). The ME is itself a fairly capable CPU - like a PC from a 2.5 decades ago, let’s say. The saucy technical details of ME and the code that runs on it are not publicly available (unless you're a big brand like Dell, I guess). The code that runs on the ME is loaded from external memory, and is encrypted, and then decrypted internally in the ME section of the chip.
In some way, the complex boot process of a modern PC - just the stuff that happens up to the BIOS starting to execute on user cores - is reminiscent of IBM Power hardware. Except the latter is not really optimized to boot fast, and is glacially slow in comparison (or at least was a decade ago).
Before the management engine even starts, though, the CPU is typically powered down. There’s a smaller system management microcontroller that configures the power supplies, starts thermal and power monitoring tasks, and releases the management engine from reset.
On the first PCs and microcomputers, the process was much simpler. There was just one CPU, and it would start fetching instructions and executing them immediately after the RESET signal went inactive.

There is no one way how it is done. Also by using the naming of BIOS and CPU you are limiting yourself to something like Intel x86 systems.
It will also differ between different eras of PC computing.
In the earliest IBM PCs and other computers of the era, it is not even loaded, it's alredy there. The memory chip with BIOS code is directly accessible by the CPU on memory bus and CPU simply starts executing from a certain memory address where the memory chip with BIOS code is wired. The addresses will also be different based on which exact CPU you mean, as they have different address bus width.
How modern systems do it is likely more complex. The BIOS being on a SPI bus etc. But it does not stop some logic circuitry or boot ROM (on the CPU or on motherboard) from transferring the SPI memory contents somewhere that the CPU can execute it.
